# jQuery scroll function stops working randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using $(window).scroll to hide my header on scroll, with an identical function as I have successfully used on another site with no problems. On this site, however, the scroll function simply stops firing randomly after some scrolling. At first I thought it was when I scrolled too fast, or scrolled immediately to the bottom of the page, but it seems to be randomly stopping however I scroll. Even something as simple as:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  console.log('scrolling');
});
```

just stops firing after a little scrolling up and down. So it's not because I'm performing some crazy actions on each scroll event.

What can cause this?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: The code looks fine, although .scroll was deprecated in favor of using window.on("scroll", function () ) so maybe try that.

The next thing I'd try would be removing all other JS from the page and retesting. It's probably a process of elimination to identify the issue as you might have some conflicting code.

Also try adding a break point in your code on the console method to see what happens and check if it's constantly firing.

Comment: no console errors. and I'm only using one scroll function. But i'll try window.on instead!

Comment: I had the same problem, but I forgot I had a .off('resize") in an other function :) Check it out!